# PHP & Regex: Insert a white space '&nbsp;' at the end of HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

How can insert the following white space HTML code `"&nbsp;"` just before closing of any of these HTML tags `<p><b><a><i><span><strong>`

For example
from this:

```
<p>Some Random Text</p>
<b>some bold text</b>
<span>some span text</span>
<p  class="classexample">some text with class</p>
```

to this

```
<p>Some Random Text&nbsp;</p>
<b>some bold text&nbsp;</b>
<span>some span text&nbsp;</span>
<p class="classexample">some text with class&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: You *could* do this with Javascript/jQuery (quite easily might I add). At any rate, [Don't use Regex to match HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/269970).

Comment: @esqew In this case, it's very clearly-defined and therefore okay as a regex.

Comment: You don't need regex. A simple str_replace will work: $html = str_replace('</p>', '&nbssp;</p>', $html);

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I suppose, my hope is that OP doesn't get hooked on the idea of applying it to broader cases than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
(<\/(?:p|b|a|i|strong|span)\b)
```

**Replacement string:**

```
&nbsp;\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yB3gO3/3)

**Explanation:**

- `()` Capturing groups.
- `<\/` Matches the string `</`
- `(?:)` Non-capturing groups. It won't capture anything, just matching would be done.
- `(?:p|b|a|i|strong|span)\b` Matches the string `p` or `b` or `a` or `i` or `span` which must be followed by a word boundary.

Comment: I would suggest adding `\b` after the alternation group, just to ensure you don't affect the wrong tags, for instance `</area>`.

Comment: Thank you @AvinashRaj i will accept your answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Well, not now you've added the `\b`, but before you added that it would most certainly match `</area>`. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yB3gO3/2)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** :

```
$var = '<p>Some Random Text</p><b>some bold text</b><span>some span text</span><p>some text with class</p>';
$var = preg_replace("(\<\/)(span|p|b|i|a|span|strong)","&nbsp;$1$2",$var);
echo $var;
```